# Wicket - Validator reporting warnings not errors and not blocking form submission

Tags: java, warnings, wicket, validation

i have a form where i have 5 `TextField`s that are required and 25 that are optional. I set the required TextFields `setRequired(true)` and get the Feedback messages i want when this fields are empty.

But how do i achieve such an effect that i get warning messages in my feedback panel when the 25 fields are empty but the form still does submit correctly? I want to inform the user that these fields are optional, but it would be nice if he would fill them.

I know i can in `onSubmit()` add warnings through the `warn()` procedure. But in on submit i can only check the model for this values, i dont have the component that is empty. But i would like to have the functionality of `Validator`s so that i can say to the user that *Field 'optionalTextField1' has no value but it would be nice if you fill it*, i can user properties for the messages and so on.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this through overriding [checkRequired()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html#checkRequired%28%29)

```
 @Override
 public boolean checkRequired() {
    if (!isRequired() && getValue().isEmpty()) {
       warn("Field'" + getLabel().getObject() + "' is empty. We suggest to fill it.");
       return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    return super.checkRequired();

 }
```

`getLabel().getObject()` requires that you `setLabel(Model.of("Nice field name"));`

Comment: Don't override checkRequired(), add a custom validator.

Comment: Show me how to write one that generates warnings not `ValidatorError`. Basicly so answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement your own IValidator pass the componente as variable and use warn, for example

```
public void validate(IValidatable<String> validatable)
{
    String value = validatable.getValue();
    if (value.isEmpty())
    {
        component.warn("some nice message")
    }
}
```

just an example, not tested though

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem with this is that if i dont input anything validation on this field is not performed, so this does not work.